# How to send form data in post request in iOS using MonoTouch?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to make a post request in MonoTouch along with my form data, I got an answer in Objective-C but was unable to do the same in MonoTouch.
Here is the objC code:

```
  NSData* postData= [<yourJSON> dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
  [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [request setHTTPBody:postData];

  NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
  [connection start];
```

Can any body help me in converting this code to mono touch code.

Comment: @ Krumelur i am completely new to monotouch so i have no idea to do this at all.

Comment: you can indeed make a port, like @krumelur suggest, but you should probably use a more .NET-y API, like WebClient or HttpClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Xamarin.iOS (MonoTouch) allows you to use the .NET Framework, you can do this the same way you would with a desktop C# app.  There are a couple of different approaches, but one way would be with WebClient:

```
   using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {

       byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://test.com/endpoint", new NameValueCollection()
       {
           { "name", "value" },
           { "name", "value" }
       });
   }
```

Searching for "C# post form data" should get you lots of other examples.